# PHP Date format for MailChimp birthday field - whats the correct format?

Tags: php, api, datetime, format, mailchimp

I am trying to update a subscriber with his birthday, but it won't accept any formats I've input.

I've tried:

```
date('d/m/Y', time());
date('d/m', time());
date('m/d', time());
```

What's wrong? Their API documentation says:

> "the month and day of birth, passed as MM/DD"

And:

> optional only valid for birthday and date fields. For birthday type,
>   must be "MM/DD" (default) or "DD/MM". For date type, must be
>   "MM/DD/YYYY" (default) or "DD/MM/YYYY". Any other values will be
>   converted to the default.

But it wont work! When imported, the birthday-field is blank.

Comment: date() is the PHP function, and the second variable should be an integer not string [check here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe is too late, but for additional searches... I discover the API need the input date in format Y-m-d.

The list field data configuration is only a format to show it.

That works to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way i implemented it:

```
$merge_vars = array( 'EMAIL' => $email,
                     'FNAME' => $name,
                     'BIRTH_DATE' => $dateMonth . '/' . $dateDay );
```

Comment: I know this is a bit old but I've been having the same issue.

The correct format is: `m/d`.

A suggestion that I would make is to let php handle your date for you, i.e:

`date('m/d', strtotime($birthday))`.

Hope this helps anybody coming across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For current Mailchimp API's version (v3) the format must be:

```
 <?php

 $birthday = date('n/j/Y');
```

So, this will generate something like **1/22/2019**

Answer (score 0):

Mailchimp API v3 needs an `MM/DD` format, in PHP it would look like this:

```php
$email = 'example@email.com';
$birthday = '16-02-1980'; // dd-mm-YYYY format or any format you'd like

$merge_fields = [
    'EMAIL' => $email,
    'BIRTHDAY' => $birthday ? date('m/d', strtotime($birthday)) : '',
];
```

We also need to check if `$birthday` is set, since an empty string will result in "01/01" as a birthday in Mailchimp (because of the `date('m/d', strtotime())`), when sending `''` it stays keep blank.